# copy files from Dropbox to AWS S3 using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, dropbox-api

I want to write python code to copy files from Dropbox folder to S3 bucket.

Here is the code I wrote so far. I can list the files in Dropbox folder. But I can't copy it to S3 because I just get the Dropbox file names.

Here is code....

```
import dropbox
import time
import os
import sys
import json
import boto3

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("accessToken")

def list_folder(dbx):
    rv = []

    for entry in dbx.files_list_folder('').entries:
         rv.append(entry.name)
    return rv

def Drop2S3(DropFiles):

    for f in DropFiles:
        data = open(f, 'rb')

    s3.Bucket('s3bucket').put_object(Key=f, Body=data)


DropFiles = list_folder(dbx)

client = boto3.client('s3')

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

Drop2S3(DropFiles)
```

Comment: Would you consider using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) instead? You could do it with `aws s3 sync dropbox-directory s3://bucket/path`

Comment: Any errors you get ?

Comment: The `files_list_folder` method just gives the file metadata. If you need the actual file data, you'll need to use [`files_download`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download).

Answer (score 0):

as Greg said, you would need to use files_download function:

```
import dropbox
import boto3
import io

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='YOUR_REGION')
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(TOKEN)

meta, res = dbx.files_download(DBX_PATH)  # gets your file from dropbox
s3.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(res.content), "BUCKET_NAME", 'S3_PATH_OR_FILENAME)
```

Note: it is a code for one file, if you need to transfer many you'll need to call it for each file.